# DropdownMenuItem with Map in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna populate two DropDownMenuItems from this Map:

```
var jobs = {
  "departments": ["dep1", "dep2", "dep3"],
  "dep1": ["job1", "job2"],
  "dep2": ["job3", "job4"],
  "dep3": ["job5", "job6"]
};
```

DropdownButton 1 (departments)

```
DropdownButton(
 hint: Text(hint1),
 value: chosenDep,
 items: jobs['departments']
        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(e), value: e,))
        .toList(),
onChanged: (value){
  setState({
     isDepChosen= true;
     chosenDep = value;
  });
)
```

DropdownButton 2 (jobs)

```
if(isDepChosen)
DropdownButton(
 hint: Text(hint2),
 value: chosenJob,
 items: jobs[chosenDep]  // here i select key of map with chosen department
        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(e), value: e,))
        .toList(),
onChanged: (value){
  setState({
     chosenJob = value;
  });
)
```

But I'm getting this error, when i choose anything from second menu and change value of first menu:

```
Assertion failed: file:///home/koha/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material 
/dropdown.dart:1473:15
items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
          items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
            return item.value == value;
          }).length == 1
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: job1. \nEither zero or 2 or
 more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the first, you have to change the second to the default value.

For example.

```
DropdownButton(
 hint: Text(hint1),
 value: chosenDep,
 items: jobs['departments']
        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(e), value: e,))
        .toList(),
onChanged: (value){
  setState({
     isDepChosen= true;
     chosenDep = value;
     chosenJob = jobs[chosenDep].first;
  });
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the items from the second dropdown, but your variable 'chosenJob' has a value from the old item list. Clean the 'chosenJob' content when you change your 'chosenDep' variable.